# Max diameter of random partition arising from optimal transport

Tags: optimal-transportation

Let $\mathbf S^2\subset \mathbb R^3$ be the sphere centered at the origin with radius chosen such that $m(\mathbf S^2)=n$, where $m$ denotes the surface area measure. Consider the Wasserstein distance $W_2(m,\mu_n)$ (of order $2$), where

$$\mu_n:= \sum_{1\le i\le n} \delta_{X_i}$$

and $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are chosen uniformly and independently at random from $\mathbf S^2$. Then there exists a (random) partition $V_1,\ldots, V_n$ of $\mathbf S^2$, i.e.

1. $\bigcup_{1\le i\le n} V_i =\mathbf S^2$;
2. $m(V_i)=1$ for every $i$;
3. $m(V_i\cap V_j)=0$ for all $i\neq j$

such that

$$W_2(m,\mu_n)^2=\sum_{1\le i\le n}\int_{V_i}|x-X_i|^2 {\rm d}m(x).$$

Denote by $R_i$ the diameter of $V_i$, i.e. $R_i:=\sup\{|x-y|: x, y\in V_i\}$. What is the law of $R:=\max_i R_i$? Or more precisely, can we find some suitable function $f$ with $f(\infty)=0$ such that $\mathbb P(R>r)\le f(n)$?